How to get dates in specific array mongo
I have mongo collection with objects with 2 fields: available_from and available_to
Mongo collection:
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("66ed4d5ede0184e906f9397a"),
    "available_from": ISODate("2024-09-20T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "available_to": ISODate("2024-09-30T00:00:00.000Z")
  }
]

I want to get all dates which are in specific array
For example my input is: {$match: {"available_from": "2024-09-20", "available_to": "2024-09-30"}} but this input still does not show me anything.
There is mongo playground:
What should i change?


Your query missed the time component, causing an exact match failure.
Please include time range along with the date.
Updated query is as follows:

db.collection.aggregate({
  $match: {
    "available_from": {
      $gte: ISODate("2024-09-20T00:00:00.000Z")
    },
    "available_to": {
      $lte: ISODate("2024-09-30T23:59:59.999Z")
    }
  }
})


Answer 1: The query in your question is:
{
  $match: {
    available_from: "2024-09-20",
    available_to: "2024-09-30"
  }
}

The only fix needed for exact-match is to covert it to ISODate:
{
  $match: {
    available_from: ISODate("2024-09-20"),
    available_to: ISODate("2024-09-30")
  }
}

Answer 1 Mongo Playground

Answer 2: The query in your linked mongo playground is:
{
  $match: {
    available_from: { $lte: "2025-09-20T00:00:00:00" },
    available_to: { $gte: "2024-09-30T00:00:00:00" }
  }
}

Notice that the time part has four pairs of 00 instead of three. The fixes needed are:

remove the extra :00
put a Z (for UTC)
convert to ISODate

{
  $match: {
    available_from: { $lte: ISODate("2025-09-20T00:00:00Z") },
    available_to: { $gte: ISODate("2024-09-30T00:00:00Z") }
  }
}

Answer 2 Mongo Playground

I think this is better than the accepted answer, in the sense that this explains the type mismatch issue and detailed construction of the date parameters.
